# UIImageView in cell not showing image

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a table view and an array named `offlineImages` that contain images stored in the Documents folder. I want this images to show in the image view of the cells. The code compiles, but does not show the image. The URLs stored, the cell identifier and the tag are correct.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "offlineCell")
    let mainImageView = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
    let mainImageURL = offlineImages[indexPath.row]
    let mainImageData = NSData(contentsOf: mainImageURL)
    let mainImage = UIImage(data: mainImageData! as Data)
    mainImageView.image = mainImage
    return cell!
}
```

Here is how I have downloaded the images:

```
let imageDestination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
    var documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    documentsURL.appendPathComponent("image."+"png")
    return (documentsURL, [.removePreviousFile])
}

Alamofire.download(mainImageURL, to: imageDestination).response { response in
    if response.destinationURL != nil {
        finalImageURL = response.destinationURL!
    }
}
```

Comment: `UIImage(data:)` returns an optional. Did you check if it's nil?

Comment: It's not nil. The URL's are correct.

Comment: Better said, it shouldn't. Actually, I've checked and they are nil. Why?

Comment: Because you can't guarantee any arbitrary Data object can be turned into an image

Comment: The images are downloaded from the Internet and stored as .jpg files in the Documents folder, so they should be turned into an image.

Comment: Have you checked if the URL for the images is being blocked?  If your app transport security does not allow the url for the images you will not be able to retrieve them... just to be sure, set your App Transport Security in the .plist to Allows Arbitrary Loads = YES and see if it works

Comment: They are downloaded from an HTTPS server so they shouldn't be blocked by App Transport Security.

Comment: I've had times that https image urls have not loaded until I add the domain to app transport security... try adding allows arbitrary loads = YES and let me know if it works

Comment: I've tried this and no improvement

Comment: Are you sure that mainImageView is not nil?

Comment: Yes, by showing directly images from web it works, but I want the images to be saved for offline viewing.

Comment: You should make url request to download those images then show it.

Comment: @Anton, did that using Alamofire.

Comment: please provide more code, so we could help

Comment: might be you'hv hidden the UIImage from interface builder

Answer (score 0):

pbb you didn't save the pics correctly. Check that.

Comment: They are saved correctly, I've tried to print the URL.

Comment: @abcd I mean the pic binary files, not just the urls

Comment: How can I check that?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "offlineCell")
    let mainImageView = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
    let mainImageURL = offlineImages[indexPath.row]
    let mainImageData = NSData(contentsOf: mainImageURL)
    let mainImage = UIImage(data: mainImageData! as Data)
    if let image1 = mainImage {
        mainImageView.image = image1
    }
    return cell!
}
```